# Error calling function when running PowerShell script from WIndows Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

I have the following simple PowerShell script:

```
foo "Hello World!"
Start-Sleep 5

function foo($message) {
    write-host $message
}
```

This works correctly when I run from the ISE. However, when I try to add this as a scheduled task in Windows I get the following error:

> foo : The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

How can I fix the script to allow it to run as a Windows Scheduled Task?

Comment: Move the function definition to the top of the script

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This was the solution. Can you add as answer (and please add a brief explanation) so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

define the function first.
You'll find it will run the 2nd time in the ISE, because of they way the [shell remembers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714451(v=vs.85).aspx). Define the function 1st:

```
function foo($message) {
    write-host $message
} 
foo "Hello World!"
Start-Sleep 5
```